# WCF service hosted in Windows service - not working

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, wcf, service

I've created the WCF service and some simple WPF application consuming it. When I'm running the project from within Visual Studio, the WCF Test Client opens and the application works just fine, method defined in service work.

But I need to host this WCF service in a Windows Service. I've followed [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx#_Step_1:_Create), installed the services using `Installutil.exe` and the ran the service. Everything went fine, it's working.

Yet, when I'm trying to open the executable file with WPF application directly from the debug folder of the app, I'm getting this error:

> zad8. has stopped working

After choosing the option to debug it with new instance of VS I get

> XamlParseException occured in PresentationFramework.dll

The stack trace shows something like:

> connection can't be started, because the target computer is actively refusing it

Do you have any idea what could go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, I've managed to come up with solution. I think I should post it, maybe one day it will help somebody:)

I actually did two mistakes, but one of them was unfortunately caused by the mentioned tutorial  ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx#_Step_1:_Create)) in connection with my temporary blackout.
In step 5, point 8 of this tutorial, there's an example of overriding OnStart() method:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
   if (myServiceHost != null)
   {
       myServiceHost.Close();
   }
   myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1));
   myServiceHost.Open();
}
```

Beware, that `Service1` is ambiguous in this context, because it's name of the Windows Service project class as well as the name of WCF Service class. It should be written with fully qualified name (here it is WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1). In my case, the service name was different, and I just put the `Service1` in there in a hurry. Anyway..

In case, someone has it all behind and still encounters the same problem (with app stopped working), I think that you should try open the project in Visual Studio and try to debug the client consuming application as a new instance (right click on the project-> Debug -> Start as new instance...).

It might seem trivial, but when u hit F5 or Ctrl+F5 then even if u have only those project set as startup project, VS will host it's client anyway. In my case it did matter, because I needed to use isolation storage file. And as it was kept on the service side, then I had this file created in IIS server created by VS. Somehow, my method of creating such file had set FileMode.Open() and it was causing the crush, because in Windows Service it didn't exist and the new one couldn't be created and that was neccessary to run it correctly.

What's more it just showed me that this question couldn't be answered properly, cause the data I've provided was not enough and it was delicate.

Cheers:)